# If $\binom{2p}{p}$ is $(-1)^{p-1} \bmod 2p+1$ is then $2p+1$ prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a positive integer; if $2p+1$ is prime then it is easily checked that
$$(2p+1)\mid\left(\binom{2p}{p}+(-1)^{p-1}\right);$$

conversely I conjecture that if the above divisibility assumption holds, then $2p+1$ is a prime number. Is this true?

Comment: This is Wilson's theorem in disguise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Comment: Your conjecture is easy to prove, and it is not of research level. Indeed, modulo $2p+1$, $(2p)(2p-1)\dots(p+1)$ is congruent to $(-1)(-2)\dots(-p)=(-1)^pp!$, hence $(2p)(2p-1)\dots(p+1)/p!$ is congruent to $(-1)^p$.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: One doesn't even need Wilson's theorem, see my previous comment.

Comment: How does one get that 2p+1 is prime from your observation?

Comment: @GHfromMO The trouble is that some of the factors of $p!$ will be zero divisors mod $2p+1$, so you can't do the division by $p!$. For example, it's not true in the case where $p = 4$.

Comment: Further, it is not clear that there isn't some p with 2p+1 composite in which 2p+1 divides the relation.  It may follow from Wilson's Theorem, but I have not made the connection yet.  Gerhard "Needs More Coffee, Of Course" Paseman, 2015.06.12

Comment: The conjecture is false.  Counterexample: $p = 2953$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Nice, I checked only for $p\le 2000$...! I  edited to remove the irrelevant tests (which concerns the converse: if $2p+1$ is prime then the divisibility holds, which as pointed out is an immediate exercise). I'm wondering why such composite $2p+1$ seem so rare.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yes, and as far as I checked, this is the only counterexample where $p \leq 10000$.

Comment: Sloane could recognize the sequence with the single term 5907 ($=2.2953+1$): the keyword seems to be "Catalan pseudoprime" or "Wilson spoilers":), see https://oeis.org/A163209; only 3 such primes are known (5907 and the squares of the two known Wieferich primes), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_pseudoprime.

Comment: Can one quickly compute $\binom{2p}{p} \bmod (2p+1) $ using previous computed smaller values?  Do I need to loop from 1 to p, or can I use the factorization of 2p+1 to speed up the computation?  Gerhard "Often Looking For Faster Ways" Paseman, 2015.06.12

Comment: (Of course, I mean "only 3 such Catalan pseudoprimes", not "only 3 such primes"! these are $5907=3.11.179$, $1093^3$ and $3511^2$.)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman If $2p+1$ factorizes into powers of small primes, you can use results of Andrew Granville http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/granville/paper/binomial/html/binomial.html to compute it mod each of these prime powers, and then Chinese Remainder Theorem to put these together.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: The original assumption (before the question was edited) was that $2p+1$ is prime. In this case $p!$ is invertible modulo $2p+1$ and my argument works. What I wanted to point out is that Wilson's theorem is not needed. Note that for $p=4$, $2p+1=9$ is not prime.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: See my previous comment (to Todd Trimble).

Comment: @GHfromMO, that might have been your reading of the original post.  Mine (and I imagine Todd's) is that the idea "2p+1 is prime" is a conjectured consequence.  Of course, if 2p+1 is an assumption, then your observation holds, and Wilson is not needed to get the congruence.  Then again, Robert  Israel's example shows Wilson is of little use here.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: I see. The original post was written in terrible English, and I was sleepy as well. Now I understand what the OP meant.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: You should post your counterexample as an answer so that the question can be closed.

Comment: for $p=1093^2$,I found can by hand  ,Note $1093^2|2^{1092}-1$,so  $(2\cdot 1093^2+1)|(\binom{2\cdot 1093^2}{1093^2}+1$

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger You are of course right; my first comment above was unfortunately a case of "shoot first, ask questions later". The relation to Wilson was supposed to be (well, at least under the proviso that $p!$ is prime to $2p+1$) that $(p!)^2 \equiv (-1)^{p-1}$ modulo $2p+1$. (There's a nice pictorial proof of that based on the graph representing the reciprocation relation on $\{2, \ldots, p\} + \{-2, \ldots, -p\}$ modulo $2p+1$.) But of course that proviso is true only if $2p+1$ is prime, leading to the same *petitio principii* objection I had raised in response to GH's argument.

Comment: Mistakes will be made.  If we are forgiving of ourselves, we can forgive others, and in such a cooperative spirit the mistakes made in this forum will be fixed.  May the original poster collectively forgive us for getting it wrong and thank us for getting it right.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger But the original question was so confusing that it was understandable that it was closed: indeed the conjecture was the same as above, but OP provides tests as an evidence for the conjecture, assuming that $2p+1$ is prime (instead of non-prime)! This led to 2 interpretations, one of which is the converse, which is an easy exercise and off-topic, the other being that the tests when $2p+1$ is prime are irrelevant (this is why I edited, removing the tests, and the question was subsequently reopened).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Also from my comment, when the question was closed)

From Robert Israel's single example $2p+1=5907$ I found in Sloane Encyclopaedia the general picture:

A [*Catalan pseudoprime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_pseudoprime) is an odd non-prime $2q+1$ satisfying $$2q+1\;\big|\;(-1)^qC_q-2,$$ where $C_m$ is the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $\frac1{m+1}\begin{pmatrix}2m \\ m\end{pmatrix}$.

Using that $q+1$ and $2q+1$ are coprime and $2(q+1)\equiv 1[2q+1]$, we see that the above divisibility condition is equivalent to the initial condition $(2q+1)\mid\binom{2q}{q}+(-1)^{q-1}$. So the Catalan pseudoprimes are precisely those odd non-primes $2q+1$ satisfying $(2q+1)\mid\binom{2q}{q}+(-1)^{q-1}$.

There are only 3 known Catalan pseudoprimes; they form [Sloane's sequence A163209](https://oeis.org/A163209); here are their prime factorization

- $5907=3\times 11\times 179$
- $1194649=1093^2$
- $12327121=3511^2$

The latter two are the squares of the two known [Wieferich primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime).

Answer (score 14):

(Posting my earlier comment as an answer) The conjecture is false. Counterexample: $p=2953$.

Comment: can you prove  $(2953\times 2+1)|\binom{2\cdot 2953}{2953}+1$ by hand?

Comment: You can do it by hand, but it would take a while. Factor 2*2953 + 1 as 3 * 11 * 179, and consider those terms which are multiples of 3 or 11 or 179 separately.  Or as Robert Israel commented, work modulo each prime.